# Scraping a web page with a "more" button...with beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape information from this website: "http://vlg.film/"

I'm not only interested in the first 15 titles, but in all of them. When clicking on the 'Show More' button a couple of times, the extra titles show up in the "inspect element" window, but the url stays the same, i.e. "https://vlg.film/". Does anyone have a or some bright ideas? I am fairly new to this..Thanks

`

```
import requests as re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = ("https://vlg.film/")
page = re.get(url)
soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')
wrap = soup.find_all('div', class_="column column--20 column--main")
for det in wrap: 
    link = det.a['href']

    print(link)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can simply add the pagination to the url. The trick is to know when you reached the end. Playing around with it, it appears once you reach the end, it repeats the first page. So all you need to do is keep appending the links into a list, and when you start to repeat a link, have it stop.

```
import requests as re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

next_page = True
page_num = 1
links = []
while next_page == True:
    url = ("https://vlg.film/")
    payload = {'PAGEN_1': '%s' %page_num}
    page = re.get(url, params=payload)
    soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')
    wrap = soup.find_all('div', class_="column column--20 column--main")
    for det in wrap: 
        link = det.a['href']
        if link in links:
            next_page = False
            break
        links.append(link)
    page_num += 1
    
for link in links:
    print(link)
```

**Output:**

```
/films/ainbo/
/films/boss-level/
/films/i-care-a-lot/
/films/fear-of-rain/
/films/extinct/
/films/reckoning/
/films/marksman/
/films/breaking-news-in-yuba-county/
/films/promising-young-woman/
/films/knuckledust/
/films/rifkins-festival/
/films/petit-pays/
/films/life-as-it-should-be/
/films/human-voice/
/films/come-away/
/films/jiu-jitsu/
/films/comeback-trail/
/films/cagefighter/
/films/kolskaya/
/films/golden-voices/
/films/bad-hair/
/films/dragon-rider/
/films/lucky/
/films/zalozhnik/
/films/findind-steve-mcqueen/
/films/black-water-abyss/
/films/bigfoot-family/
/films/alone/
/films/marionette/
/films/after-we-collided/
/films/copperfield/
/films/her-blue-sky/
/films/secret-garden/
/films/hour-of-lead/
/films/eve/
/films/happier-times-grump/
/films/palm-springs/
/films/unhinged/
/films/mermaid-in-paris/
/films/lassie/
/films/sunlit-night/
/films/hello-world/
/films/blood-machines/
/films/samsam/
/films/search-and-destroy/
/films/play/
/films/mortal/
/films/debt-collector-2/
/films/chosen-ones/
/films/inheritance/
/films/tailgate/
/films/silent-voice/
/films/roads-not-taken/
/films/jim-marshall/
/films/goya-murders/
/films/SUFD/
/films/pinocchio/
/films/swallow/
/films/come-as-you-are/
/films/kelly-gang/
/films/corpus-christi/
/films/gentlemen/
/films/vic-the-viking/
/films/perfect-nanny/
/films/farmageddon/
/films/close-to-the-horizon/
/films/disturbing-the-peace/
/films/trauma-center/
/films/benjamin/
/films/COURIER/
/films/aeronauts/
/films/la-belle-epoque/
/films/arctic-dogs/
/films/paradise-hills/
/films/ditya-pogody/
/films/selma-v-gorode-prizrakov/
/films/rainy-day-in-ny/
/films/ty-umeesh-khranit-sekrety/
/films/after-the-wedding/
/films/the-room/
/films/kuda-ty-propala-bernadett/
/films/uglydolls/
/films/smert-i-zhizn-dzhona-f-donovana/
/films/sinyaya-bezdna-2/
/films/just-a-gigolo/
/films/i-am-mother/
/films/city-hunter/
/films/lets-dance/
/films/five-feet-apart/
/films/after/
/films/100-things/
/films/greta/
/films/CORGI/
/films/destroyer/
/films/vice/
/films/ayka/
/films/van-gogh/
/films/serenity/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple web site to extract data. Create a urls list of web page , how many page do you want to extract. Then use for loop to iterate all page extract the data.

```
import requests as re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

urls = ["http://vlg.film/ajax/index_films.php?PAGEN_1={}".format(x) for x in range(1,11)]

for url in urls:

    page = re.get(url)
    soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')
    wrap = soup.find_all('div', class_="column column--20 column--main")
    print(url)
    for det in wrap:
        link = det.a['href']
        print(link)
```

Comment: Please Upvote /accept this/any Answer which is useful to you